# Automapper, mapping exception

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I use Automapper in many locations in the code in my solution. But I don't understand why in one project of this solution, I do this :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MY_CLASS, MyClass>();

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var result = Mapper.Map<List<MY_CLASS>, List<MyClass>>(myListResult);
```

I get this exception on the `Mapper.Map` line :
*Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping*

In the configuration, I ignore all properties except one, the `Id` field, same exception

I really don't understand why. Is there a way to know with more precision the problem ?

**Update 1**

failed MyTestMethod threw exception: 
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
MY_CLASS -> MyClass
MyProject.DataContexts.MY_CLASS -> MyProject.BusinessModels.MyClass

Destination path:
List`1[0]

Comment: both Id has same Type?

Comment: Can you post the full exception message?

Comment: @nemesv see update1, I tried to convert a single object and not a list, I get the same exception

Comment: Are you sure that `Mapper.CreateMap<MY_CLASS, MyClass>();` gets called before the `Mapper.Map`? And also make sure that you have `Mapper.CreateMap<MyProject.DataContexts.MY_CLASS, MyProject.BusinessModels.MyClass>();` maybe you have more types with the same name in different namespaces...

Comment: Yes CreateMap is called before Map and no other class with the same name

Answer (score 5):

As there is no answer to this, I'd like to add that nemesv's comment to the question pointed me in the right direction. That being the CreateMapper statements weren't executed, resulting in the same exception as OP's.